# Does the Windows 10 ISO have a EI.CFG file for changing the edition?

Tags: iso-image, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

The ISO image of both Windows 7 and Windows 8 had a file `ei.cfg` that could be modified to allow a user to install any edition of Windows.

Since I am going to install the Windows 10 operating system on several different machines with different configurations, I would like to minimize the number of downloads I have to do in order to save bandwidth and time.

I would therefore like to know if the Windows 10 ISO also have this file for changing the windows edition (`ei.cfg`) or I have to download each one separately.

Comment: Have you looked to see if that is the case?

Comment: @Ramhound: I haven't been able to do so because I am still in the process of downloading my first ISO. I just wanted to know if anyone else had verified if this is the case.

Comment: I suspect if the .ISOs downloaded with tool do not contain one, they would still support, being given one.  I do know that I was able to create an .ISO that contained both the x86 and x64 installations of Windows 10.  Of course what that actually does is literally, place both installations, on the same disk.

Comment: Since you've downloaded the ISO already can you please check if that file is present?

Comment: In 36 hours when I have access to the file I can do that.

Comment: 36 hours is quite a long way away. Barring any interruptions in my internet connection I am pretty certain I would have found out on my own by then. Thanks anyway. ;-)

Comment: Related: [Can you make a Windows 10 ISO with both Pro/Home and 32/64-bit flavors?](http://superuser.com/q/948450/219095)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found that the Windows 10 does not have a `ei.cfg` file like in Windows 7 and Windows 8. Microsoft however provides two "All Editions" versions in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors. Also, due to the layout of the disc, it is possible to combine both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of both of the "All Editions" discs in order to create a "Universal Install Disc"

I explain below how to obtain 32-bit or 64-bit All Editions disc and then a Universal Install Disc

### How to download a Windows 10 All Editions Disc

1. With a web browser running on any operating system apart from Wiindows 7 or Windows 8 (e.g. OSX, Linux, Android, Windows XP), visit https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO.
   You can also modify your User Agent to falsely report your operating system if your browser supports it before clicking on the link.
2. Select the edition you want to download (i.e. Windows 10, Windows 10 KN, Windows 10 N, Windows 10 Single Language) and then click **Confirm**.
3. Select the language you want to download and then clck **Confirm**.

You will now be presented with two buttons for downloading the 32-bit and/or 64-bit versions of Windows 10. The links are valid for 24 hours after which they expire.

### How to create a Windows 10 Universal Install Disc

1. Download both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows 10 as shown above.
2. Download the disc layout from [here](http://download.futuretech.in/Win10MultiIsoBase.zip).
3. Extract the Win10MultiIsoBase.zip file to a destination of your choice.
4. Merge the contents of the Windows 10 ISO images with the extracted files by extracting the contents of the 32-bit ISO into the x86 folder and the 64-bit ISO into the x64 folder.
5. Using [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download), create an ISO image with the merged data.
   Remember to make the image bootable by following these steps:

   - Select the **Advanced** tab and then the **Bootable Disc** tab.
   - Check the **Make Image Bootable** check box.
   - Download and use [this file](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/2Cd65cL2/0/blob?download) as the **Boot Image**.
   - Choose **`80x86`** as the **Platform ID**.
   - Enter `Microsoft IMAPIv2` as the **Developer ID**.
   - Enter `07C0` as the **Load Segment**.
   - Enter `8` as the **Sectors to Load**.
6. Optionally, burn the ISO to disc. You will have to use a DVD DL since the image file generated will be larger than 4.7 GB.
   After completing my download and examining the ISO, I have found that there is no `ei.cfg` file.

Credit to [DOOManiac](https://superuser.com/q/948450) for finding how to download the ISO images and [Danial B](https://superuser.com/a/948536) for the Windows 10 Multi-ISO base layout.

---

---

#### Original Post:

After completing my download and examining the ISO, I have found that there is no `ei.cfg` file.

I am still searching for a way to achieve 'universal' install capability and I'll update this answer when I find one.

Comment: From within Win7Pro x64, the download procedure is somewhat different: I opened the MS website in your link and downloaded the Win 10 download manager `MediaCreationTool1803.exe`. This in turn can be used to download the 32 and 64 bit versions of Win 10 for different languages. However in this tool I had no choice of the editions (N, KN, etc.). Don't know if this matters: I am in Germany.

Answer (score 5):

As Windows 10 build 10586 (also called version 1511 – for November 2015 – or Threshold 2) has come out since this question was asked, I'm going to write an up-to-date answer.

The short answer is no, there is no `ei.cfg` in the `.iso` by default.

If having an all-in-one `.iso` containing Windows 10 Home and Pro 32-bit and 64-bit is what you want, this is fairly easy to do with the updated Media Creation tool that was released along with the November 2015 update.

---

## 1) Preparation

You have two options. If you want to start with a 'template', go to **1.1) Downloading the template**. If you prefer to start from scratch, follow **1.2) From scratch**.

#### 1.1) Downloading the template

1. Go to this [OneDrive folder](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2B00DAC5B10FE6CC!22554&authkey=!ANsixzaATBpqOqY&ithint=folder%2czip).
2. Right-click on "Windows10AIO" and click on "Download" *([VirusTotal rating](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/8f577cb24bd79cc61180194855dc48e54790980f2377724825df7608c74a7fd6/analysis/1455407496/))*.
3. Extract the downloaded archive to your `C:` drive. You should now have a `Windows10AIO` folder in your `C:` drive, which contains an empty `iso` folder, a `programs` folder, `ei.cfg` and `oscdimg.exe`.
4. Install 7-Zip if you don't have it (or a similar program) installed already from the `C:\Windows10AIO\programs\7-Zip` folder (use `7z[version].exe` if you're following this guide on a 32-bit system, and `7z[version]-x64.exe` for a 64-bit system).

#### 1.2) From scratch

1. Create a folder called `Windows10AIO` in your `C:` drive (so `C:\Windows10AIO`).
2. In that folder, create a folder called `iso` (so `C:\Windows10AIO\iso`).
3. Download 7-zip from [its website](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and install it (if you don't have a program that can extract `.iso` files installed already).
4. Download the Windows 10 Media Creation tool from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and save it to `C:\Windows10AIO\programs\Windows 10 Media Creation tool` (create the `programs` and `Windows 10 Media Creation tool` folders first).
5. Download the [Windows 10 Assessment and Deployment Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721(v=vs.8.5).aspx) (WADK) and install it (you need only the Deployment Tools, so untick everything else during installation).
6. Copy `oscdimg.exe` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg` to `C:\Windows10AIO`.
7. Download the portable version of Rufus (`rufus-2.6p.exe` at the time of writing) from [here](https://rufus.akeo.ie/#download), and save it to `C:\Windows10AIO\programs\Rufus`.
8. Open Notepad and input the following text:

   ```
   [Channel]
   Retail
   ```
9. Save this file as `ei.cfg` to `C:\Windows10AIO`. Make sure "Save as type:" is set to "All files (*.*)" when saving.

---

## 2) Downloading the `.iso`

1. Run the `MediaCreationTool.exe` and accept the license.
2. Select "Create installation media for another PC" and click on "Next".
3. Untick "Use recommended options for this PC" if it's ticked.
4. 1. Select the language you want.
   2. Make sure "Windows 10" is selected next to "Edition" (unless you don't want/need Windows Media Player, in which case you select "Windows 10 N").
      You may notice that you can't choose between Windows 10 and Windows 10 Pro. This is because they're both included in the `.iso` by default.
   3. Select "Both" for the architecture.
5. Click on "Next".
6. Choose "ISO file" and click on "Next".
7. Save the `.iso` to `C:\Windows10AIO\iso` as `Windows10.iso`.
8. Do something else while the Media Creation tool downloads and verifies the Windows 10 installation files, and makes an `.iso` out of them (unless you really like watching progress screens and percentages).
9. Click on "Finish".

---

## 3) Adding `ei.cfg` to the `.iso`

1. Navigate to `C:\Windows10AIO\iso` with File Explorer, right-click on `Windows10.iso` and select "7-Zip" > "Extract Here". If you have another decompression program installed, use that to extract `Windows10.iso` to `C:\Windows10AIO\iso`.
2. Once everything is extracted, delete `Windows10.iso`.
3. There should now be four folders in `C:\Windows10AIO\iso` (`boot`, `efi`, `x64` and `x86`), and four files (`autorun.inf`, `bootmgr`, `bootmgr.efi` and `setup.exe`).
4. Copy `ei.cfg` from `C:\Windows10AIO` to `C:\Windows10AIO\iso\x64\sources` **and** `C:\Windows10AIO\iso\x86\sources`.
5. Navigate to `C:\Windows10AIO` in File Explorer, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and right click in an empty space. Click on "Open command window here".
6. In the Command Prompt that appears, type (or copy and paste) this and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   oscdimg -lWindows10AIO -m -o -u2 -udfver102 -bootdata:2#p0,e,bC:\Windows10AIO\iso\boot\etfsboot.com#pEF,e,bC:\Windows10AIO\iso\efi\microsoft\boot\efisys.bin C:\Windows10AIO\iso C:\Windows10AIO\Windows10AIO.iso
   ```
7. There should now be a `Windows10AIO.iso` file in `C:\Windows10AIO`.

## 4) Making a bootable USB/DVD

If you want to create a bootable Windows 10 installation USB-stick, follow **4.1) USB**.
If you want to create a bootable DVD, follow **4.2) DVD**.
If you don't want to do either, this is the end of this guide.

#### 4.1) USB

1. Plug in your USB-stick (must be at least 8 GB).
2. Start `rufus-2.6p.exe` from `C:\Windows10AIO\programs\Rufus`.
3. Change the settings so they are like this:

   - **Device**: the USB-stick you just plugged in.
   - **Format options**

     - **Create a bootable disk using**: ISO Image.
     - Click on the button next to the dropdown box and select `C:\Windows10AIO\Windows10AIO.iso`.
   - **Partition scheme and target system type**

     - "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" if the computers you're going to install Windows 10 on all have an UEFI BIOS, or "MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI-CSM" if the computers you're going to install Windows 10 on all have a legacy BIOS (pre-UEFI), or if some have UEFI and some have BIOS.
   - Leave the other settings as they are.
4. Double-check that the right USB-stick is selected, and make sure that there's nothing important on it.
   If there is, this is your last chance to back everything up, as the USB-stick will be formatted while making it Windows 10 installation media.
5. Click on "Start" and wait until Rufus has finished.
6. Et voilà! You've created an all-in-one bootable Windows 10 USB-stick.

#### 4.2) DVD

1. Insert a double layer DVD in the disc tray.
2. Navigate to `C:\Windows10AIO` and right-click on `Windows10AIO.iso`.
3. Select "Burn disc image".
4. Make sure the correct disc burner is selected, optionally tick "Verify disc after burning", and click on "Burn".
5. Et voilà! You've created an all-in-one bootable Windows 10 DVD.

---

- For more information about `oscdimg.exe`, check [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749036%28WS.10%29.aspx).

  - The example on [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947024) was used as basis for the `oscdimg` command line options in my answer.
- For more information about `ei.cfg`, check [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn938370(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

#### Disclaimer

- The Windows Media Creation tool and `oscdimg.exe` both copyright Microsoft.
  I have no affiliation with Microsoft, nor do I claim to have any affiliation with the company or its employees.
- Rufus – copyright Pete Batard/Akeo.
  I have no affiliation with him or his website.
- 7-Zip – copyright Igor Pavlov.
  I have no affiliation with him or his website.

Comment: Amazing post! Thanks for taking time to give the "from scratch" option. For anyone on Windows 8 (not 8.1) you can get the ADK tools here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30652

Comment: This worked for me. I wanna just point out. I wanted to install Windows 10 Home N on a laptop. First time I started the installation it asked me which version I wanted, but I quit the installation. When I started again it just auto picked regular edition. Then I had to go through all this to get the N version.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an AIO iso you'll have to capture and append each version install.wim files. BUT you will not be able tu do OS upgrades with that AIO.

Upgrades can only be done with the corresponding version of Windows.

For example if you are using Windows 8.1 Pro the upgrade can be done with a Windows 10 Pro install disk/iso, not with an AIO even if it has the Windows 10 Pro installation files.

But an AIO works well, there is no ei.cfg needed.

I installed each version (W10 home & W10 Pro both 32 and 64 bits) on virtual machines, made my few customisations (like an OEM would do) in oobe mode, then captured each one in a install.wim file with dism, then appended them all into one install.wim file.

Then, I put it in the source folder of the 64 bit iso version of Windows 10 home (pro is working too) and that's it, working like a charm.

Of course if you don't know how to use virtual machines/oobe/dism you'll have to learn or wait for another guy to release en AIO on the internet.

Comment: This sounds like the answer I need. I'll have to download both ISO images in order to have the ability to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, in your case, to upgrade all your machines you'll need to download (with the download-to-iso tool microsoft provided) both Home and Pro iso. each can be made with both 32 and 64 version so you should be able to upgrade all your machines with only 2 iso. Glad if I helped :)

Comment: That’s not true. AIO (well, Home/Pro) images from MSDN can upgrade perfectly fine.