# How to burn Windows 10 (x86) as bootable disk from ISO

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, 32-bit

I have downloaded the ISO image by running the media creation tool. While creating the media, I had chosen both 64-bit and 32-bit.

The downloaded ISO file is 5.47 GB.

I am trying to use that to do a clean install on a x86 machine which is running Windows 7.

How can I make a bootable disk of Windows 10 only with the x86 components and not the x64 because, when I try to write the ISO image there is not enough disk space on the DVD (4.7 GB is the size).

I cannot download the ISO image and do a install as the internet connections are a bit flaky and the download will never finishes. :-(

**What I have**

1. An ISO image generated by running the media creation tool as specified [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) under the section titled *Perform a clean installation using a USB or DVD*
2. When I extract the ISO image using 7zip, I get the following. Note that there is both x64 and x86. [image]

**What I need**

1. A bootable disk which can be written to a DVD

How do I do this?

Comment: Rerun the media creation tool and this time make separate iso's for each bit version.

Comment: @Moab: Thanks, but as mentioned, the internet connections are very poor and I wouldn't be able to download the ISO for each bit version separately.

Comment: Try deleting the x64 folder before you make the disk

Comment: @Moab: Yes, that is what I did per my comments in the answer provided by Dr. Ping. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a bootable USB. Obviously, you'll need an 8GB USB stick. There are many free tools that can do that for you (including the command line) I find ImgBurn to be very easy and simple.

You'll create the bootable USB from the iso file, not from the extracted files.

Comment: Thanks, don't have a 8 GB USB. Can I do the same for a DVD. If so, how can I separate the x64 and do the bootable aspect and x86 alone?

Comment: I don't remember if this will help or not, but give it a try. Download it again, but just x64 or x86, whichever you need. Hopefully that will be smaller to fit on a DVD.

Comment: If that doesn't work (not small enough), and you can't get a 8GB USB, I don't see how you can do a clean install. Maybe someone else will have other ideas. You can run the setup.exe and do a regular (non clean) install.

Comment: Ah, the problem is the poor internet connection. Trying now by creating an ISO file from the files (mentioned in the image as part of the question) excluding x64 and see if I can write that to a DVD. Will keep you updated. Thanks once again!

Comment: Dunno if that'll work. Interested though. Please report results :)

Comment: If you're installing x86, there's a good chance that it will be small enough. x64 is always bigger than x86

Comment: I was able to create an x86 image as mentioned in the comment with your recommended tool of ImgBurn. Do you mind editing your answer so that I can mark it as accepted? Thanks once again!

Comment: Nice. What was the ISO size of just x86? Will edit tomorrow (23:30 here...)

Answer (score 1):

You can always buy double layer DVDs, they do have enough space for 5.7GB installation files.

Although you could buy 8GB (16GB etc) USB stick for the same cost or less.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://superuser.com/q/948450/219095), ISO images (the so-called “multiple editions” image can be obtained by not using Windows—or spoofing the User Agent.

Go to [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) while not “using Windows” and complete the steps. You will be provided with a direct ISO download containing both Home and Pro edition, but only one of x86 and x64.