# Can I install Windows 10 Home using the Pro DVD?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer

I have the ISO of Windows 10 Pro downloaded with the Media Creation Tool. Is it possible to use this ISO to install the Home edition of Windows 10?

If it is possible, are they any extra hoops I need to run through? With Windows 7 and 8, you needed to used the [Ei.cfg removal tool](http://code.kliu.org/misc/winisoutils/). Is this still needed with Windows 10 and does the same tool still work?

Answer (score -2):

Simply mount the iso file and copy all things to a FAT-32 flash disk. Then boot from this disk, you shall have the chance to choose which edition to install. 
Attention: if you are to reinstall current version, you can not downgrade win10 and keep your application and file at mean time. For example, you want to downgrade from pro to home, you cannot keep your system partition. If you want a clean reinstall, you can delete your system partition and choose the blank it left to proceed. 
Or you could go back to origin system, mount the iso file and double click setup.exe to try your fortune. But this mean usually does not work.

Answer (score -3):

It is possible, but you need to put the iso onto a **usb disk.** (4GB or more, I reccomend 8GB just in case)

Now download the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](https://wudt.codeplex.com/) and install it, afterwards open it and select the ISO file, click USB then let it do its job.

Once it says its completed, go to Computer (Or this pc) and click your USB.

Then navigate to the sources folder and delete the `ei.cfg` file.

When you load your windows 10 installer from usb, it will show all windows installations!

Comment: This answer (http://superuser.com/questions/948303) suggests that there is no ei.cfg file in the Windows 10 ISO. Have you personally done the steps you describe above and verified they will work?

Comment: Yes I have tried the steps myself and they worked.

Comment: The reason it shows all versions is because it is being installed offline (clean) and does not detect a current version of Windows so it can match the version, when you do an in-place upgrade it will detect the correct version for the upgrade and not offer any other. Doing a clean install will also ask for a W10 product key.

Comment: I can't say I actually believe that you have tried this as I have literally just downloaded the ISO using the Windows 10 download tool at https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 then created a USB stick using your tool from https://wudt.codeplex.com/ and there is no `ei.cfg` file in the `sources` folder.  I can believe that you did this for Windows 7 or 8, but *not* Windows 10.