# How can I tell if win 10 media eg usb, is home or pro?

Tags: windows-10

How can I tell if win 10 media eg usb, is home or pro?

I made a win10 usb some time back and would like to know if it is win10 home or win10 pro

**EDIT**

USB made with win10 media creation tool

Comment: Any ISO for Windows 10 Version 1511 contains both Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional by default.  Any ISO for Windows 10 before 1511 the option to include both was simply optional.

Comment: See also: [Does the Windows 10 ISO have a EI.CFG file for changing the edition?](https://superuser.com/questions/948303/does-the-windows-10-iso-have-a-ei-cfg-file-for-changing-the-edition)

Comment: See this [article](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-see-which-build-and-edition-of-windows-10-the-iso-file-contains/).

Answer (score 0):

If you bought a retail or OEM version of Windows 10, the packaging should indicate the edition of Windows 10 and the system will install the correct edition. IIRC, the retail version contains data for all editions of Windows, although it is configured to only install the edition on the packaging, and (of course) provides a license only for that edition.

If you made the installation media yourself (e.g. with the media creation tool), then it does not matter because data for all editions of Windows 10 is included on the same media, though whether it contains the 32-bit or 64-bit version or both depends on what you selected when you created the media. In that case, select the edition for which you have a license on the system you're installing Windows 10 on.

Comment: looks like after it asks for a product key, if you click to do it later then it asks you what edition.  If the USB was made with the media creation tool,  any idea what the default is?

Comment: @barlop - I suspect whichever version is the first entry.  Since it is possible to configure a Windows 10 installation media to only include a specific version or include Single Language  and K/N editions of Windows 10 on the same disk, the order would be configured by the author of the ISO.  In other words it is still possible to create an AIO Windows 10 installation media